# Splitting text to column by qualifiers with SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2008, split

I'm looking to split records from 1 column to many columns. The data is comma delimited with columns that are text wrapped with double quotes. While there is no comma in text that is wrapped by quotes, SSIS and the import wizard will parse the data fine.
The problem is when double quote wrapped text contains a comma - this comma fools SSIS and the wizard into splitting that column into 2 column.

For example:

> "abc", "def", 123, "ghi, jkl", 456

Should come out:

```
col1  col2  col3  col4     col5  
abc   def   123   ghi,jkl  456
```

I've found ways on splitting by delimiter but how can I include a "skip" when the comma is between double quote?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did to get the results you are looking for.  Basically change your comma delimiter to contain another character (or two in my case) so you can easily distinguish between a comma that belongs in the string and a delimiter.  The only problem you may have is with the numbers that aren't wrapped in quotes.

```
Declare

@s nvarchar(max),
@split char(3),
@x xml

Set @s = '123","123,abc","345","345,def';
Set @split = '","';

Select @x = CONVERT(xml,'<root><s>'+Replace(@s,@split,'</s><s>')+'</s></root>');

Select [Value] = T.c.value('.','varchar(20)')
FROM @x.nodes('/root/s') T(c)
```

Results:

```
123
123,abc
345
345,def
```